# Precise transliteration of Chinese words in Python

Tags: python

I have this two words in Chinese:

```
l1 = '陕西省'
l2 = '山西省'
```

and their transiliterations are 'Shaanxi Sheng' and 'Shanxi Sheng'. I'm using the python unidecode package

```
import unidecode    
print(unidecode.unidecode(l1), unidecode.unidecode(l2))
```

but it gives me the same transliteration for both words (i.e. Shanxi Sheng). I've tried to use also packages as pypinyin and xpinyin

```
from pypinyin import pinyin, Style

def transliterate_with_pypinyin(text):
    result = pinyin(text, style=Style.NORMAL)
    return ''.join([item[0] for item in result])

from xpinyin import Pinyin

def transliterate_with_xpinyin(text):
    p = Pinyin()
    return p.get_pinyin(text, '')
```

but they give me also the same result. Any idea on how to achieve a precise result?

Comment: have you tried `pinyin` library ?

Comment: You can also try using google translator library for python. https://thepythoncode.com/article/translate-text-in-python

Comment: pinyin gives me 'shǎnxīshěng' and 'shānxīshěng', so with a different 'a' but I need the transliteration without special characters. Google translate gives me 'Shaanxi Province' and 'Shanxi Province' so it gives me a good transliteration but only of the first part of the words

Comment: It is not valid, in the first place, to say that "the" transliteration of any text in a foreign script "is" anything at all. You've found two libraries so far that disagree with you about what the result should be; other than "look for more libraries until you find one that agrees", or "manually check for specific points of disagreement and override what the library says", I can't understand how you expect the question to be answered. In the first case the question is off topic (we **explicitly** don't recommend libraries) and in the second it is unclear (what difficulty did you encounter?).

Comment: I'm not a Chinese expert at all, the difficulty I encountered is to distinguish the unidecoded forms of the two chinese words in the question. Since they are two different regions of China (Shaanxi and Shanxi), I wanted to know how to achieve these transliterations starting from the two chinese words

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple solution, the Shaanxi versus Shanxi example involves a non standard variation in Romanisation, so any potential solution will have to first address the exceptions.

Chinese place names use pinyin for transliteration into Latin script, except for 陕 in 陕西省, which uses Gwoyeu Romatzyh transcription for easier distinction with 山 in 山西省.

I will use the `pinyin` module.

The code below, first replaces 陕 and 省, introducing a space before sheng. It then converts remaining Hanzi to Pinyin, and finally strips out the diacritics and title cases the result:

```py
import pinyin
import unicodedata as ud
def override_pinyin(data):
    return data.replace('陕', 'shaan').replace('省', ' sheng')
def strip_diacritics(data):
   return ''.join(c for c in ud.normalize('NFD', data) if ud.category(c) != 'Mn')
def custom_pinyin(data):
    data = pinyin.get(override_pinyin(data))
    return strip_diacritics(data).title()

print(custom_pinyin('陕西省'))
# Shaanxi Sheng
print(custom_pinyin('山西省'))
# Shanxi Sheng
```

Comment: you are right, the transliteration of '省' is 'Sheng', I've edited the question, my mistake, sorry. So basically, there isn't a package that transcribes in the Gwoyeu Romatzyh form? Because I need a general solution to avoid cases like this, not only for Shaanxi and Shanxi

Comment: The problem is that only that one character uses the Gwoyeu Romatzyh form, ie rest of the characters in Shaanxi Sheng use pinyin. As far as i can tell 陕 is a unique exception. For 陕西省, 陕 uses the older romanisation, and 西省 uses pinyin. Will update my answer re sheng.